# Cleaning up the DNA tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Seeing an influx of DNA questions recently (by influx I mean 1 question a day as opposed to the usual 0), I thought it might be worth cleaning up the DNA tags a bit.

We have:

[dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dna)

- [mitochondrial-dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mitochondrial-dna)
- [y-dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y-dna)
- [autosomal](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosomal)
- [xdna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xdna)
- [haplogroup](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haplogroup)

All of which makes good sense. [dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dna) should be used on all DNA-related questions, and then the appropriate subgroup of testing as applicable.

The minor changes I propose, for the sake of consistency and to satiate my OCD:

- Rename [autosomal](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosomal) to [autosomal-dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosomal-dna). A benefit is that when a user asking a question enters a tag name and types in "dna", then autosomal-dna will also come up as a suggestion. Otherwise users might not think to search for just "autosomal".
- Could [xdna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xdna) please be renamed [x-dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-dna) (note the hyphen)? Just for consistency. SE gets upset when I've tried to change it, so I guess it has to be done by a higher-up.

Comment: I think I've fixed the [tag:x-dna] problem and will fix [tag:autosomal-dna].  Let me know if things don't work as expected.

Comment: Looks good, cheers @JanMurphy

Comment: I added proposed tag definitions and usage guidance for SNP and Big-Y, I don't have permission to do anything but propose them.